# Is there a way to display an image to the "triggerParameterHints" window in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, image, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to display an image in the `triggerParameterHints` window in Visual Studio Code?

Example:

[image]

(Ideally) I would like to do this within a Python `__init__` method:

```py
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        <img src="path\to\the\image">
        """
```

(I am just using an `img` markup tag, this doesn't actually do anything)

**If this is possible, but not in Python, please still let me know!**

Comment: have you tried to type some markdown in the doc string to see if that is picked up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried some Markdown.

I could not find a markdown syntax for bold and italic text.

It recognizes the image. It shows the alternate text of the image in the tooltip plus a missing image icon.

I have not found a way to get the HTML of the tooltip to see what image path is set.

The python file and the image are in the root of the workspace.

````python
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        ## Header

        Some `literal text`

        A [link](http://www.google.com)

        ![Test image](tstimg.png)

        Some code with syntax highlighting

        ```
        def func(arg1, arg2):
          print("Hello")
        ```
        """
        self.a = 5

x = TestClass()
````